# How to navigate from 1 activity to another in the Master / Detail View of Android Studio using a button?

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, master-detail

I am currently working on a project using Android Studio. In this project, I need to Implement a mobile application using Master / Details view activity. Each item in the list directs the user to certain activity.

Let's say Item 1 directs the user to an activity named (selln.class). This activity has a button that sends the user to another activity (BookInfo.class).

The problem I am facing now is that the buttons aren't responding to the onClick() listener so when I run the application on the emulator and try to click on the button, nothing happens!

***Here is the code I am using for the button click:***

```
Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login_Btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(selln.this,BookInfo.class));
            }
        });
```

Also the same exact problem happens when I try to display an activity after showing a splash screen for few seconds.

**This is the selln.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cover"
android:id="@+id/Layout">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="@string/pass_Txt_Input"
    android:hint="password"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Login_Btn"
    android:id="@+id/Login_Btn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="@string/Email_Txt_Input"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/sign"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Login_Btn"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the selln.class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class selln extends ActionBarActivity {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selln);

        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login_Btn);
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(selln.this,BookInfo.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btn is working :/", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(selln.this,SignUp.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_book_info, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

***My Question is how to fix this ?***

Please help .. I really need to test the functionalities of those activities :'(

Comment: check if its working by log, or toast, or manual debug, if you shure it's not, paste whole code here

Comment: It should be working. Post your complete Layout and Activity code.

Comment: ok .. I will add the code here.

Comment: I tried the toast as well but it didn't work :/

Comment: The question is edited .. Appreciating your help :)